# Prevent mobile phone to blackout / go into standby

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, mobile

I am currently developing a website mainly for mobile phones, but it's  similiar to a fullscreen video, you don't want the screen to turn off!
Is there anything I can do to prevent the screen to go black / the phone to go into standby?

This has to work without any apps, but I am able to use any JS library.

Comment: Thankfully, that's not possible. I'd be very unhappy if I accidentally left the browser open and found that your website has drained my battery.

Comment: That would be the same problem with any app then...

Comment: No, because an *app* will have to request permission to receive a wakelock. I wouldn't expect a website to do that.